# adding image to svg file using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, svg

I'm trying to add an image to an SVG file..
I tried this code::

```
drawImage : function(src, x, y, h, w) {
        var img = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "image");
        var $img = $(img);
        $img.attr('x', x);
        $img.attr('y', y);
        $img.attr('width', w);
        $img.attr('height', h);
        $img.attr('xlink:href', src);
        $('g').append($img);
    }
```

but the image does not appear.
when I select all images.. using `$('image')` I find the image, and I can select it, but still.. it is not visible.
I tried to investigate this issue, but found nothing.
what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a jQuery plugin that solved my problem [jQuery.svg](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/svg)

it has several methods to draw different shapes, including images.

It seems that it adds images by creating a dom node using native JavaScript.. and it works

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `setAttributeNS` method:

```
var img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','image');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'height','200');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'width','200');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'id','theID');
img.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink','href','src');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'x','0');
img.setAttributeNS(null,'y','0');
$('#g').append(img);
```

Comment: it is a simple function.. I don't think I need a full library just to do a simple task.
and as I commented on the first answer, I created similar functions to draw (rect, circle, path,.. etc) and they work fine, and they look similar to this, but I can't see the problem in it

Comment: using "setAttributeNS" didn't work either
it created this element `<image height="300" width="300" href="images/stair.png" x="5000" y="5000"></image>` and it did not show in the screen ( chrome developer tool says its location is at (0,0) !!)

Comment: in the setAttributeNS calls, only the xlink one is correct, all others should pass null as the first argument.

Comment: If no namespace is required, you can use `setAttribute()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute

Answer (score 1):

How about assigning a width and height to `$('g')`, which is holding the `$img`  in your code?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I doubt this is the problem, as I created other elements (rect ,circle, path .. etc) and all of them are drawn on the screen, besides, I don't think I can have that ability (changing width and height of g)